# Why am I having trouble on the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Mike Hartl at section Listing 5.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coding-style

When I load up the Rails server, my home page comes up fine. However, after I input the code from section 5.1 to update "app/views/layouts/application.html.erb" with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <%= link_to "sample app", '#', id: "logo" %>
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li><%= link_to "Home",    '#' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Help",    '#' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError in Static_pages#home
undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x38ac7e0>:0x472fce0>
```

This is the extracted source (around line #4):

```
1: <!DOCTYPE html>
2: <html>
3:   <head>
4:     <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
6:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Can anyone explain why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add this to your `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`?

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end
end
```